# how to control increments with a variable in python for loop

Tags: python, c++

Here is a for loop in `C++`, how can I achieve the same in with `for` loop in Python? Incrementing `i` by `k+1`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < some_string.size();) {

  int k = i;
  while (some_condition) ++k;
  i = k+1;
  // ....


}
```

Comment: Do you search ?

Comment: What do you mean of `skip duplicate characters` and `key` in comments?

Comment: @mohammad sorry ignore the comment please

Comment: @Stargateur yes, I did search before posting this.

Comment: @shangsunset So what do you want to achieve? I can easily convert your c++ code to python code, and I think you can do so, too. I think you want something else.

Comment: @mohammad I want increment `i` by `k+1` but dont know how to do it in python.

Comment: Have you considered using a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop in the python version ? Then you can do whatever you want with `i` inside the loop.

Comment: @bli thats a good point :) I guess its impossible to do it with `for` loop?

Comment: What have you tried, and what went wrong?  What were you expecting to happen instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following lines of code do the same thing as c++ code in question; however, I don't know if this is the goal you want to achieve:

```
i = 0
while i < len(some_string):
    k = i
    while some_condition:
        k += 1
    i = k + 1
```

Comment: Thanks I ended up using `while` loop instead. I thought there was way in python `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the possible solution.

```
for i in xrange(len(some_string)):
    k = i
    while some_condition:
        k += 1
    i = k + 1
```

Comment: @shangsunset what do you mean by i won't skip?

Comment: @Saurav I suppose this means that the modification of `i` at the end of the loop body is ignored in the next pass. The loop variable cannot "skip" some values.